# Inserir valor no Input Value com JS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou tentando trazer um valor que ao clicar em um botão traga em um input isso funciona mas o valor não aparece dentro do **Value** do input com isso não consigo capturar esse valor via PHP.

### Segue o código

https://jsfiddle.net/felipefranco/2fkje6m4/3/

**Botão**

```
<a href="#my_modal" data-toggle="modal" data-fornecedor-id="<?php echo $rowPedido->id; ?>"><img src="img/lupa.png"  ></a>
```

**Input**

```
<input type="text" name="idPedido" id="idPedido" value="" />
```

**JS**

```
  $('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
var idPedido = $(e.relatedTarget).data('fornecedor-id');

document.getElementById('idPedido').value = idPedido;    

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para exibir o valor no atributo 'value' como deseja, faça da seguinte forma:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-AddBookDialog", function () {
     var myBookId = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body #bookId").attr('value', myBookId );
});
```

Note que usa-se **.attr('value', myBookId )** ao invés de **.val(myBookId )**

https://jsfiddle.net/2fkje6m4/7/

Comment: Valeu Gustavo  deu certo era isso mesmo!!

Answer (score 1):

Tenta dessa forma e me diga se funcionou o que você queria:

```
$('#my_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {

  var $target = [];
      $target['fornecedor-id'] = $(event.relatedTarget).data('fornecedor-id');
      $("#idPedido").val($target['fornecedor-id']);

});
```

Comment: Esse código faz a mesma coisa do que eu estou usando ele imprime na tela mas não aparece dentro do Value=" "

Comment: Criei um Modelo no Jsfiddle se você olhar ele imprime o resultado na tela mas quando vc olha com o firebug o value está em branco.

https://jsfiddle.net/felipefranco/2fkje6m4/3/

Comment: para aparecer dentro da value, isso tem que estar impresso na página antes do evento: `<?php echo $rowPedido->id; ?> `

Comment: mas isso é obvio... vc está fazendo jquery... vc tem que inspecionar o elemento depois do javascript.

Comment: Não tem problema nenhum no código?

Comment: [Olha como o valor foi enviado para o documento](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/2fkje6m4/4/)

Comment: Quando você inspeciona um elemento html, as mudanças de javascript não aparecerão nunca. Porque o javascript não envia isso para o servidor. Para ver as mudanças ocorrendo, vc tem que assistir no código fonte enquanto envia a requisição.

Comment: Mas quando eu dou $_POST no PHP esse valor vem em branco

Comment: Mas daí é outro problema, vc tem que fazer um formulário. um input sozinho não envia mesmo. A menos que seja uma requisição ajax. e o valor do input seja capturado, para um objeto de envio.

Comment: Eu sei disso aqui só trouxe uma parte do código esse input está dentro de um Form o que não está dando certo é capturar esse valor pois o campo **Value** tá em branco

Comment: Olha esse [outro exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/8kL53kcf/). Imagine que esse dado esteja sendo enviado para uma página PHP.

Comment: Ao invés de /echo/json/ seria no PHP: `$_POST['dado']`;